# Why is day_num not defined?

Tags: python

```
for day_num in range(1,8):
        sales=float(input("Enter the sales for Day {}".format(day_num)))
        bakery_temp_info.append(sales)
    bakery_sale.append(list(bakery_temp_info))
    del bakery_temp_info[:]
```

This is a section of an exemplar code that my teacher gave me. Can anyone explain how the variable "day_num" is used for this loop when it has not been previously defined. I have tried printing it out in the loop and it increases by 1 every time the loop runs. Any help appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Just read about `for` loops. This question is answered in any elementary python programming book.

Comment: You may be find useful giving a look at the python [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#for).

Comment: The code you posted has an IndentationError and won't run. That's probably not related to your question, but you do need to fix it, both here and in your actual code.

Comment: Are you confused because you learned another language first, and want to know how Python is different from that language? If so, if you tell us what language your intuitions come from, we can probably explain the difference better.

Answer (score 2):

Python variables don't have to be declared; the first time you assign to one, it's created.

And almost anything that assigns a value to a name counts as an assignment, not just actual `=` statements. That includes:

- `name = …`
- `while (name := …) > 0:`
- `for name in …:`
- `import name`
- `with … as name:`
- `def func(name):`

… and so on.

Each of these assigns a value to `name` in the current scope (except for the last one, which only assigns a value in the scope of the function body). It doesn't matter whether `name` was a variable before that statement or not; it is one now.

---

If it isn't clear where any assignment is happening, your `for` loop is equivalent to this `while` loop:

```
_range18iter = iter(range(1, 8))
try:
    while True:
        day_num = next(_range18iter)
        # body of the for loop
except StopIteration:
    pass
def _range18iter
```

Now it's obvious that, as long as the iterable is not empty, `day_num` is going to be assigned to.

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring `day_num` in the loop. Basically the loop is telling the interpreter that you want to iterate over something and want to give each iteration a name, in this case `day_num`.

The iterable you are providing in this case is a range from 1-8, but you could just as easily pass it a list. In that case you would be calling each element of the list `day_num`, as an example.

Every time you run through the loop, it updates the value stored in `day_num`.